# Flutter Web App Blank Screen in Release mode

Tags: firebase, flutter, web, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I have a Flutter Web App which renders just fine on running
`flutter run -d chrome`
But if I run `flutter run -d chrome --release` It gives me a blank screen.

How should I sort out this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flutter build web
```

use this code

Comment: I have already tried flutter build web & flutter build web --release & then running flutter run still result is same.
The web app works properly in debug mode but not in release mode.

Comment: @user7856586 Unfortunately No

Comment: @RahulKumarJha  I deleted the project and then downloaded it again

Comment: @RahulKumarJha yes

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter create .
```

you should see now web folder in your project
inside web folder under index.html
comment below code(you will find it inside head tags)

```
<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
```

this will fix your blank screen problems