# flutter web built release but nginx route 404

Tags: flutter, nginx, flutter-web

Similar case:
[flutter-web-app-blank-screen-in-release-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63545088/flutter-web-app-blank-screen-in-release-mode)

I have an AWS EC2 cloud server. and I built a flutter web build in my EC2 Server.
and cross-connect the flutter web index.html to Nginx.

```
> $ flutter build web

 Building with sound null safety 

Compiling lib/main.dart for the Web...                           1,491ms
```

so EC2 can 200 OK.
[image]

and routed navigate another page and refreshed.
[image]
[image]

my EC2 Server nginx config is:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/flutter_web_project/build/web; # <- the flutter build web released result folder

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

and i used url_strategy dependency

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

    url_strategy: ^0.2.0
```

and main.dart source:

```
...
import 'package:url_strategy/url_strategy.dart';

void main() {
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'flutter web sample',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: locationPlatform(),
      onGenerateRoute: WebRouter.generate,
      initialRoute: '/',
    );
  }
...
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try update nginx config.
It will work for direct url.

```
 location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try update nginx config. It will work for direct url.
>
> ```
> location / {
>    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
> }
> ```

Addition comment the following line:

```
# include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```